# Unknown word error in react-datepicker component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, datepicker

i do

`npm install react-datepicker --save`

https://reactdatepicker.com/

next, I use the component in my project

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
```

in the `render` function:

```
render(){
    return(
        <DatePicker />
    );
}
```

the project is compiled with - webpack:

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'order.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'style-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|woff2?)$/,
        use: 'url-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError

(2:1) Unknown word

  1 |
> 2 | var content = require("!!./react-datepicker.css");
    | ^
  3 |
  4 | if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];
```

Comment: try with order change in webpack css loader, put style-loader first and css-loader second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you change the order?

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
 }
```

Loaders always execute from left to right.

and import `react-datepicker-cssmodules.css`

```
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';
```

Comment: which webpack version are you using?

Comment: I am sorry, It helped me.